# Как понять определение px на примере iPhone 5?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, вёрстка, frontend

1 px по определению в css [это](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#values) 1/96 inch.
В [описании](https://www.devicespecifications.com/ru/model/70af28ac)(возможно не самый надежный источник) ширины экрана(не корпуса) у iPhone 5  = 1.96inch  по определению [=>](https://www.unitconverters.net/typography/inch-to-pixel-x.htm) 188.16px.

Ок, есть другое определение пикселя для [разрешения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) экранов.
iPhone согласно [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_5) имеет разрешение 640x1136 пикселей.

Ок, но когда я открываю chrome toggle device toolbar(Ctrl+Shift+M) и выбираю iPhone 5 отображается 320х568. Странно, но это значение не совпадает ни с одним из 2 значений приведенных ранее(но если присмотреться, то ширина и высота ровно в 2 раза меньше чем 640x1136).

Откуда значение 320х568? Есть ошибка в источниках или рассуждения?

Comment: Дюймы и прочие сантиметры не обязательно имеют отношение к реальным дюймам и прочим сантиметрам. Если я правильно понимаю современный стандарт, на экранах можно привязаться к reference pixel, который в случае айфона оказывается 2x2 пикселя https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#reference-pixel

Comment: В CSS дюймы и прочие «реальные» единицы прибили гвоздями к пикселям. В частности, 1in определён как 96px. И не волнует какого размера пиксель в реальности. Это может быть пиксель вашего монитора и тогда «дюйм» примерно равен настоящему. А может быть пиксель биллборда размером в сантиметр и тогда «дюйм» будет размером в метр

Comment: Про hidpi https://pepelsbey.net/pres/clear-and-sharp/

Comment: Можно подробнее про 2x2 или другую ссылку, по этой ссылки не увидел раскрытия данной темы?

Comment: https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: если говорить очень грубо, то есть пиксели программные, есть точки(физические пиксели), на ретина дисплеях повышенная плотность точек, например, у айфона 5 "двойная" плотность физических пикселей, то есть один программный пиксель содержит 4 физических (2х2), есть тройная, тогда в одном программном будет 9 физических (3х3), есть четверная (4х4). Отсюда и выходит, 320 css пикселей это 640 физических на 5-м айфоне, на X это вообще 1280(вроде)