# Как проверить работу min-width/max-width @media на примере iPhone 5 в браузере десктопа?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, responsive, frontend

[Разобравшись с тонкостями значения px](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950063/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-px-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-iphone-5), встает вопрос о том как проверить верстку с `@media` в браузере на десктопе.

При использовании `@media min-width/max-width` необходимо указать px(не разрешения, а именно 1/96 inch, но если я не прав - поправьте).

Ок, у iPhone 5 `width = 1.96inch = 188.16px`.
Но инструмент chrome toggle device toolbar(Ctrl+Shift+M) при выборе iPhone 5 отображает ширину 320(разрешение).

Похоже что toggle device toolbar приравнивает значения px разрешения и "1/96 inch" px, так как правила `@media min-width/max-width` отрабатывают на значения разрешения которые отображает chrome.

Представим устройство Х у которого width тоже 1.96inch, но ширина разрешения = 1440px.

При равных физических размерах экранов у них будет разное разрешение. Я хочу сверстать сайт одинаково для этих 2 устройств. И при попытки проверки этих 2 устройств в браузере десктопа у меня будут совсем разные размеры и как следствие `@media` будет себя по разному вести.

Как это сделать?

Comment: считайте, что у айфона 5 ширина экрана 320px(css px) и всё, остальное, физические пиксели, по сути вам не интересны, это уже использует устройство для лучшей четкости изображения. В моем lg, например, ширина 1080 физических пикселей, но это 360 css пикселей. По суди, единственное место, где вам интересны физические пиксели, точнее плотность пикселей - это растровые изображения, вот они должны быть х2, если двойная плотность пикселей у устройства, х3, если тройная и т.д.

Comment: даже, если вы выполните js код, который покажет ширину экрана, что-то типа `alert(window.innerWidth)`, то на 5-м айфоне вам покажет 320px, а не 640

Comment: Вадим Лешкевич, я вижу тут проблему не в 640. Проблема в том что 2 устройства с одинаковым количеством css px и разным разрешением будет не возможно проверить(что они одинаково отображаются или что для всех устройств с одним и тем же css px @media правила будут отрабатывать одинаково) в десктопном chrome.

Comment: просто не обращайте внимание на фактическую плотность пикселей, вас интересуют только css пиксели.

Comment: `Проблема в том что 2 устройства с одинаковым количеством css px и разным разрешением будет не возможно проверить` - на них одинаково будет отображаться, еще раз, повышенную плотность пикселей дисплеи используют только для улучшения четкости изображения, вас же интересуют только css пиксели

Comment: то есть, есть 3 устройства у одного фактическая ширина 360(стандартная плотность), у другого 720(двойная плотность), у третьего 1080(тройная плотность). Так вот на них отображение сайта будет абсолютно идентичным, т.к. для браузера у них у всех ширина 360px, разница будет **только** в чёткости картинки

Comment: @Вадим Лешкевич. Смущает что беря 320px на устройствах в chrom toggle device toolbar, задавая в сss значение media (min-width: 320px) {...}, (max-width: 319px){...}. Хочу проверить работу media min-width/max-width в браузере меняю с 320 на 319 - работает, но физически этот экран 1.96inch = 188.16 css px. Почему я задаю в правилах не css px (188.16)?

Comment: Забудьте про физические размеры телефона. Для CSS они не имеют значения.